# download a file from the web and save to S3

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

This Meteor server code (part of an app) running on the local machine downloads a file from the web and saves it to the AWS S3.
This Meteor app also runs on EC2 docker container. but when the below modifications are made, it failed to run as `docker ps` does not show a running container.

The modifications runs ok on the local machine which downloads a file from the web and uploads it to AWS S3.
Any ideas how to fix it so that when runs on the EC2 docker container it downloads the file and saves it to the AWS S3? Thanks

```js
// server

    let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    fs = require('fs');
    let request = Npm.require('request');

    Meteor.startup(() => {
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: 'abc',
      secretAccessKey: 'xyz'
    });
    let url = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";

    let fileArray = url.split("/");
    let file = fileArray[fileArray.length - 1];

    // (((it would be good if copying locally is avoided)))
    // let localFilePath =  "/home/ec2-user/"+file;    // <=== fails on EC2 
    let localFilePath = "/local/path/ + file; // <=== works locally

    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFilePath)).on("finish", function() {
      fs.readFile(localFilePath, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("file does not exists");
          throw err;
        }
        let base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');
        let s3 = new AWS.S3();
        s3.putObject({
          Bucket: 'myBucket',
          Key: file,
          Body: base64data,
        }, function(resp) {
          console.log(arguments);
          console.log('Successfully uploaded package.');
          fs.unlink(localFilePath);
        });
      })
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the local docker file system is read only, so you can't save a file locally. See this answer to a similar question: [Allow user to download file from public folder Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813313/allow-user-to-download-file-from-public-folder-meteor-js/39816347#39816347)

There are several Meteor packages to help you with this, such as https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/files You can do a search on Atmosphere to find a suitable package

Comment: Since the ultimate objective is to save the file to S3, How can the option #2 in the link you provided be achieved without saving a local copy?

Comment: That's why I gave you the link to that Atmosphere package, the examples will show you how. This is a common problem, which they have made easy for you

Comment: Thanks, Would you freelance it for me?

Comment: Mmm, possibly, contact me via hangouts, I have a gmail account which is mikkel.j,king

Comment: @FredJ. let me know if you are still interested in getting some help